# How do I use gnuradio installed using Macports?

Tags: macports

I have used gnuradio companion in Linus.  I am trying to migrate to macOS Sierra.  I used Macports to install and it completed without error.

How do I run gnuradio now?

When I type "gnuradio-companion" in /opt/local/bin I get the following errors:

> (process:37834): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GMountMountFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
>
> (process:37834): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GDriveStartFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
>
> (process:37834): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GSocketMsgFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/opt/local/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 97, in 
>       check_gtk()
>     File "/opt/local/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 64, in check_gtk
>       die(err, "Failed to initialize GTK. If you are running over ssh, "
>     File "/opt/local/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 42, in die
>       import gtk
>     File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py", line 69, in 
>       _init()
>     File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py", line 57, in _init
>       warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
>   gtk.GtkWarning: could not open display

Suggestions?

Comment: Some useful info here: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/MacInstall

Comment: Linos (some Linux distro) or Linux?